# Access original token in ADFS

Tags: adfs2.0

is it possible to access original token in ADFS 2.0?

i mean, if the SAML token comes as the input to the ADFS i want to add this complete token in the transformation rule to the claim for the output.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this?

Normally, the SAML token is sent from ADFS to the RP. The RP can get at the token by using BootstrapToken.

The token is only an ADFS input for federation.

Comment: yes, my scenario is federation.. I have IdP - ADFS - SharepPoint. I receive SAML2 as input to ADFS and i Sent SAML1 to the Sharepoint, because of SharePoint limitation... But I also need to access to the original SAML2 token in the sharepoint for another purposes.. and i am asking if it is possible to attach the original saml2 token to the saml1 token as custom claim... but it seems, that it is not possible to access token from adfs.